# How to query plan cache for all query's using a table variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, plan-cache

Is there a way to query the sql plan cache for all query's using a table variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is you could use the system **DMVs** to do a wildcard contains search on the cached **query plans'** text like so:

```
SELECT databases.[name] AS DatabaseName, Plans.objtype AS ObjectType, PlanText.text AS PlanText
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS Plans -- Cached Query Plans
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(Plans.plan_handle) AS PlanText -- Query Plan Text
INNER JOIN sys.types -- Data Types (inclusive of User Defined)
    ON PlanText.[text] LIKE '%' + types.[name] + '%'
INNER JOIN master.sys.databases -- Databases
    ON PlanText.[dbid] = databases.database_id
WHERE types.is_user_defined = 1
    AND types.is_table_type = 1 -- Filter on only the User Defined Table Types
```

This will return the database of the cached **query plan**, the object type (View, Procedure, Ad-Hoc etc), and the **query plan's** text itself. One potential downside to this is if you have a **user-defined table type** that has a very common name used for other things in other queries, and therefor you might get extra results back due to *false positives* on the contains search.

Comment: Does that query really show table variable usage? To me it seems to show usage of table types, which is a different thing from table variables...

Comment: @TiborKaraszi That's a good point, potential inline table variable creation and usage without a predefined table type. I'm so used to using predefined table types to create them instead, which is what the above will catch since the type name will be part of the query. I'll have to think of the case you mentioned as that is probably harder to do without some sort of **RegEx** / **Patten Matching** expression instead.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, a real table can still be called `[@sometable]` the same as a table variable, but this is still a useful filter. The definitive XQuery filter seems to be that there is no `@Database` attribute on a node named `Object`.

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
select qp.query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(p.plan_handle) qp
where qp.query_plan.exist('//Object[empty(@Database) and substring(@Table[1],1,2)="[@"]')
```